# How to safely filter elements in collection?

Tags: java, kotlin, collections, java-stream

I have data class Product:

```
data class Product(
    val name: String,
    val code: String?
)
```

And I need to get product name from product list by given code. Here is my code in Kotlin:

```
 val productList = getProductList()
    val codeToFind = "1234"

    val nameByCode = productList.firstOrNull { it.code == codeToFind }
        ?.name ?: ""
```

Is it possible to write the same concise and safe code in the Java using Stream API ?

Comment: Sure there is. Did you try? Look at methods like `filter()`, `findFirst()` in `Stream` and `map()`, `orElse()` in `Optional`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String nameByCode = getProductList().stream()
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)  // filters null values in the list
           .filter(it -> codeToFind.equals(it.code))
           .findFirst()               // returns java.util.Optional wrapper
           .map(it -> it.getName())   // null-safe operation on the wrapper
           .orElse("");               // fallback value
```

Links:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it can throw NullPouinterException if product list has null value.

Comment: I think it's better to use `codeToFind.equals(it.code)` instead of `it.code == codeToFind`

Comment: @testivanivan updated the example with `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: @Ivo ofc, u're right, obviously I missed that  `code` is a `String`) updated the example